# Dynamic object html - alternate between objects drawn by function on canvas and use range/slider to change pattern

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm writing a web app using html,javascript,css.

I have made two dynamic functions, one draws triangles and the other circles.
When I move the slider it creates a pattern from images drawn.
When I mouseclick on the canvas it changes from triangles to circles.

The problem is after I change from triangles to circles by clicking on the canvas and I try to move the slider the image goes back to the original (triangles).
Also I can click on the canvas to change from triangles to circles but cannot change it back with another click.

This is what I want to do:

1º - I want to click on the canvas and change from triangles to circles back and forth, alternate between figures with a click on the canvas.

2º - After clicking on the canvas to alternate images - the slider must change the pattern created that is shown on the canvas - and not go back to the original unless I click again on the canvas.

I provide the code bellow. Hope you can take a look a it.
Thanks for your time.

[image: Triangle_Start]
[image: After clicking on the canvas changes to circles]
[image: After using the slider to change pattern - notice that it should still show circles and not go back to triangles but still change the pattern/modulation of the figure.]

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <style>
    .etiq1{font-family:verdana; font-size:15px;}
    #screen, #vect{border: 1px solid #000000;background-color:#0000FF;}
    input {text-align: right;}      
    </style>
    <script>
    var screen,vect,paint,pR;
        function inicGraf(){
            screen = document.getElementById("screen");
            paint = screen.getContext("2d");
            pR=document.getElementById("pR");
        }
        function triangle(x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,side,colorLine,colorInside){
            paint.strokeStyle=colorLine;
            paint.lineWidth=1;
            paint.beginPath();
            paint.moveTo(x,y); paint.lineTo(x1,y1); paint.lineTo(x2,y2);
            paint.closePath();
            paint.fillStyle=colorInside; paint.fill(); paint.stroke();
        }
        function triangleFour(x,y,side){
            triangle(x,y,(x+side),y,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#E6B569","#E6B569");
            triangle(x+side,y,x+side,y+side,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#AA8D49","#AA8D49");
            triangle(x+side,y+side,x,y+side,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#013D55","#013D55");
            triangle(x,y+side,x,y,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#449779","#449779");
        }
        function patternFour(modul){
            var i,j,tam=500/modul;
              for(i=0;i<modul;i++){
                for(j=0;j<modul;j++){
                    triangleFour(i*tam,j*tam,tam)           
        }
        }
        }
        function circscreen(x,y,radius,colorLine,corFundo){
            paint.lineWidth=1; paint.strokeStyle=colorLine;
            paint.fillStyle=corFundo;
            paint.beginPath();
            paint.arc(x,y,radius,0,2.0*Math.PI);
            paint.closePath();paint.fill();paint.stroke();              
        }
        function circscreenBlue(x, y, side) {
            var r1 = (side / 2.0),
                r2 = (((side / 2.0) * 80.0) / 100.0);
                    circscreen(x + r1, y, r1, "#449779", "#449779");
                    circscreen(x + r1, y, r2, "#013D55", "#013D55");
        }
        function circscreenCream(x, y, side) {
            var r1 = (side / 2.0),
                r2 = (((side / 2.0) * 80.0) / 100.0);
                    circscreen(x, y + r1, r1, "#E6B569", "#E6B569");
                    circscreen(x, y + r1, r2, "#AA8D49", "#AA8D49");
        }
        function patternCirc(modul) {
            var i, j, tam = 500 / modul;
              for (j = modul; j >= 0; j--) {
                for (i = 0; i <= modul; i++) {
                circscreenCream(i * tam, j * tam, tam);
        }
            for (i = 0; i <= modul; i++) {
                circscreenBlue(i * tam, j * tam, tam);
        }
        }
        }
        function monitor(){
            var cR; 
            cR=document.getElementById("cR");
            pR.value=cR.value;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="patternFour(pR.value)">
    <canvas id="screen" width="500" height="500" onclick="patternCirc(pR.value)"></canvas>
        <input id="pR" size="1" value="4" min="1" max="30" />
        <input id="cR" type="range" value="4" min="1" max="30" step="1" onchange="patternFour(pR.value)" onmousemove="monitor()"/>
        </div> 
    <script>
    inicGraf();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Describe how your current code failing to provide you with your desired results!

Comment: I want to be able to alternate the image on the canvas with a click, back and forth. Also after clicking on the canvas and changing the image the slider must work with the pattern seen on the canvas and not go back to the original.

Comment: Right now I'm using onclick="patternCirc(pR.value)" on the canvas to change the image to circles but I'm not able to change it back with another click. Maybe this can be achieved with a if statement but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a boolean value in a variable and toggle it each time you click. Then use that value to determine which function to call. Here I tried to leave most of your code as-is, and introduced `isCirc`, `drawPattern` and `patternToggle`:

```
  function patternToggle(value) {
    isCirc = !isCirc;
    drawPattern(value);
  }

  function drawPattern(value) {
    if (isCirc) patternCirc(value);
    else patternFour(value);
  }
```

You can run the code inline below:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <style>
    .etiq1{font-family:verdana; font-size:15px;}
    #screen, #vect{border: 1px solid #000000;background-color:#0000FF;}
    input {text-align: right;}      
    </style>
    <script>
    var screen,vect,paint,pR,isCirc=false;
        function inicGraf(){
            screen = document.getElementById("screen");
            paint = screen.getContext("2d");
            pR=document.getElementById("pR");
        }
        function triangle(x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,side,colorLine,colorInside){
            paint.strokeStyle=colorLine;
            paint.lineWidth=1;
            paint.beginPath();
            paint.moveTo(x,y); paint.lineTo(x1,y1); paint.lineTo(x2,y2);
            paint.closePath();
            paint.fillStyle=colorInside; paint.fill(); paint.stroke();
        }
        function triangleFour(x,y,side){
            triangle(x,y,(x+side),y,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#E6B569","#E6B569");
            triangle(x+side,y,x+side,y+side,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#AA8D49","#AA8D49");
            triangle(x+side,y+side,x,y+side,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#013D55","#013D55");
            triangle(x,y+side,x,y,x+(side/2.0),y+(side/2.0),side,"#449779","#449779");
        }
        function patternFour(modul){
            var i,j,tam=500/modul;
              for(i=0;i<modul;i++){
                for(j=0;j<modul;j++){
                    triangleFour(i*tam,j*tam,tam)           
        }
        }
        }
        function circscreen(x,y,radius,colorLine,corFundo){
            paint.lineWidth=1; paint.strokeStyle=colorLine;
            paint.fillStyle=corFundo;
            paint.beginPath();
            paint.arc(x,y,radius,0,2.0*Math.PI);
            paint.closePath();paint.fill();paint.stroke();              
        }
        function circscreenBlue(x, y, side) {
            var r1 = (side / 2.0),
                r2 = (((side / 2.0) * 80.0) / 100.0);
                    circscreen(x + r1, y, r1, "#449779", "#449779");
                    circscreen(x + r1, y, r2, "#013D55", "#013D55");
        }
        function circscreenCream(x, y, side) {
            var r1 = (side / 2.0),
                r2 = (((side / 2.0) * 80.0) / 100.0);
                    circscreen(x, y + r1, r1, "#E6B569", "#E6B569");
                    circscreen(x, y + r1, r2, "#AA8D49", "#AA8D49");
        }
        function patternCirc(modul) {
            var i, j, tam = 500 / modul;
              for (j = modul; j >= 0; j--) {
                for (i = 0; i <= modul; i++) {
                circscreenCream(i * tam, j * tam, tam);
        }
            for (i = 0; i <= modul; i++) {
                circscreenBlue(i * tam, j * tam, tam);
        }
        }
        }
        function monitor(){
            var cR; 
            cR=document.getElementById("cR");
            pR.value=cR.value;
        }
      
      function patternToggle(value) {
        isCirc = !isCirc;
        drawPattern(value);
      }
      
      function drawPattern(value) {
        if (isCirc) patternCirc(value);
        else patternFour(value);
      }
        

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="patternFour(pR.value)">
    <canvas id="screen" width="500" height="500" onclick="patternToggle(pR.value)"></canvas>
        <input id="pR" size="1" value="4" min="1" max="30" />
        <input id="cR" type="range" value="4" min="1" max="30" step="1" onchange="drawPattern(pR.value)" onmousemove="monitor()"/>
    <script>
    inicGraf();
    </script>
</body>
```